# HTTP Status 404 – Not Found in Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

I am a beginner of spring boot. I want to write the HelloWorld programming in spring boot. I did the one while running the project I got the error was HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
what I tried so far I attached below.pls, help me to solve the problem write an efficient way.

[image]

**Controller**

```java
@Controller
public class SecondController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String viewHomePage(Model model) {

        return "index";
    }
}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
      <title>Insert title here</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Welcome to Jsp</h1>
   </body>
</html>
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix:/
spring.mvc.view.suffix:.jsp
```

Answer (score 0):

You have imported the dependency `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your pom.xml file. So you need a database. To solve this problem you can use a h2 database:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
    <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Or you can remove the `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` dependency for a while if you don't need them at first. If you want to do another first tutorial, I can recommend this [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/) from Spring.

**EDIT**:

You are missing two necessary dependencies to use jsp:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now you can put your .jsp file in the `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` or in the `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/` folder and add the property `spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/` to the application.properties file.

Comment: i did as you said i got the error was HTTP Status 404 – Not Found any problem with model

Comment: I guess that the .jsp files are misplaced. Did you set the property `spring.mvc.view.prefix`? Or you can put the .jsp files in the folder `src/main/webapp/`. Do you get a detailed error message?

Comment: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template [index], error

Comment: I created a small example for myself and adapted the post. Two dependencies are missing and the .jsp file has to be put into the right folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Property file is wrong.
   You can have `application.properties` or `application.yml`. Since you are using properties the properties need to be defined as below:

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=src/main/resources/templates/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

2. Failed to configure a DataSource: 'URL' attribute is not specified Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class

Spring Boot is opinionated, meaning depending on what dependencies you have brought it, it tries to instantiate such beans. You have to include MS-SQL/Postgres DB. Now the issue is, seeing these dependencies in the classpath(let's consider simple in case you don't understand what classpath is- you have included these dependencies in the pom file). So since SpringBoot cannot figure out the db details, it is throwing this error. Provide the DB details in the properties file as below:

```
spring.datasource.url= provide the URL here
spring.datasource.username = username
spring.datasource.password = password
```

You can google and follow any tutorial on the internet to do so in case of stuck.

[Tutorial Link](https://www.javainuse.com/spring/SpringBoot_HelloWorld)

Comment: i did as you said i got the error was HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Comment: Check if you annotated your controller class with @Controller

Comment: @Controller  put corectway