# JSP file [/WEB-INF/createForm.jsp] not found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp

I have the following project structure:

[image]

There's my controller class:

```
package com.mikhailovskii.lab1;

import com.mikhailovskii.lab1.exception.BaseException;
import com.mikhailovskii.lab1.exception.ElementNotFoundException;
import com.mikhailovskii.lab1.exception.ElementsAlreadyExistsException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import java.net.BindException;

@Controller
public class StudentsController {

    private final StudentsRepository studentsRepository;

    public StudentsController(StudentsRepository studentsRepository) {
        this.studentsRepository = studentsRepository;
        System.out.println("init StudentsController");
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/student/new")
    public String createForm() {
        return "createForm";
    }

    @PostMapping(value = "/add")
    public ModelAndView addStudent(@ModelAttribute Student student) throws ElementsAlreadyExistsException {
        studentsRepository.addStudent(student);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("student");
        modelAndView.addObject("student", student);

        System.out.println("Add student");

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/student/{id}")
    public ModelAndView getStudentById(@PathVariable("id") int id) throws ElementNotFoundException {
        Student student = studentsRepository.getStudentById(id);

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("student");
        modelAndView.addObject("student", student);

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/students")
    public ModelAndView getStudents() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("list.jsp");
        modelAndView.addObject("student", studentsRepository.getStudents());

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BaseException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleCustomExceptions(BaseException exception) {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", exception.getMessage());

        return modelAndView;
    }

    @ExceptionHandler(BindException.class)
    public ModelAndView numberFormatError() {
        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
        modelAndView.setViewName("error");
        modelAndView.addObject("message", "Error with parsing number attribute");

        return modelAndView;
    }

}
```

There's `createForm.jsp`:

```
<%--
  Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
  User: ASUS
  Date: 13.09.2020
  Time: 23:34
  To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
--%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Add students</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/add">
    <table>
        <caption>Student Information</caption>
        <tr>
            <td>ID</td>
            <td><label>
                <input name="id"/>
            </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Name</td>
            <td><label>
                <input name="name"/>
            </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Age</td>
            <td><label>
                <input name="age"/>
            </label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input class="button" type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

There's build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0-SNAPSHOT'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.10.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

group = 'com.mikhailovskii'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/milestone' }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/snapshot' }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:5.4.0'
    implementation 'javax.servlet:jstl:1.2'
    implementation 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:8.0.21'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-jasper:9.0.38'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:2.3.4.RELEASE'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    providedRuntime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

When I try to open the URL http://localhost:8080/student/new, I see this on the webpage:

[image]

As I understand, folder, which keeps all jsps (web-inf/views/) is set correctly to application.properties:

spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/views/

So, can you please help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance!

**UPD**

I checked this question, removed jpa dependency, but still got the same error. Moved jsps to resources/templates/ and changed properties to spring.mvc.view.prefix=/ and spring.mvc.view.prefix=src/main/resources/templates/ but it didn't help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTTP Status 404 – Not Found in Spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63976684/http-status-404-not-found-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Could you put the jsp files into `/main/resources/templates` directory?

Comment: @flaxel remove jpa dependency, but it didn't help

Comment: @MustafaÇil did it, but id also didn't help

Comment: Please add the two dependencies, put the files in one of the folders (`src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp/` or `src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/jsp/`) and change the `spring.mvc.view.prefix:/WEB-INF/jsp/` property.

Comment: @flaxel but my files are already in the webapp/web-inf/views, aren't they?

Comment: No they are not. They are in the `web` folder, but not in the `webapp` folder.

Comment: @flaxel can I just create it or I should add any framework support for it?

Comment: You can just create the folder and import the dependencies.

Comment: You can't directly access pages in the WEB-INF folder.