# I cant start my spring boot project, error 404 when i run

Tags: java, spring-boot, pom.xml

This is my controller which should open the index page

```java
@Controller
public class index {
    
    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I will not display the html page because is too long

This is my pom.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.zetcode</groupId>
    <artifactId>cinemaweb</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>cinemaweb</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Тhese are the project directories

[image: project_directories]

When I run my project browser show me 'HTTP Status 404 – Not Found' and I read other post but i dont find fix, help me guys

I try to with this 2 links
http://localhost:8080/cinemaweb or
http://localhost:8080/index

Comment: This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63977334/10951752) can be helpful for you. Please read the edit part.

Comment: can you share the application.properties file or if you have set the value for `server.servlet.context-path`

Comment: my application.properties file is empty

Answer (score 0):

Use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

```
@RestController
public class index
{
    @GetMapping("/index")
    public String index()
    {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Better use the @RestController instead of @Controller
2. then @GetMapping(value = "/index") on the method - instead of @RequestMapping
   then the url is: http://localhost:8080/index

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a String as an Object, then use @RestController or @ResonseBody annotaion, like this

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody String get() {
    return "index";
}
```

}

Also I highly reccomend you to replace spring-web dependecy for spring-boot-starter-web, I
mean this

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Than Spring boot will take care about all required beans, e.g. dispatcher servlet etc.